# How get the text from a listbox item?

Tags: javascript, listbox

When I try to get the text from a Listbox item in javascript it always returns undefined.

```
winkeloptie.value = winkels[i][0]; 
winkeloptie.text = (winkels[i][0]);

alert(winkeloptie.value) ///This returns the value very nicely
alert(winkeloptie.text) //Returns undefined
```

How can I get the text?

edit: for more info:

```
function addWinkels(){
    var winkellijst = document.getElementById('winkel');
    for (var i = 0;i < winkels.length;i++){
        var winkeloptie = document.createElement("Option");
        winkeloptie.text = (winkels[i][0]);
        winkeloptie.title = (winkels[i][1]);
        winkeloptie.value = winkels[i][0]; 
        winkellijst.options.add(winkeloptie); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `select` with *listbox*?

Comment: R u sure the `ListBox` object has a `Text` property?

Comment: I am sorry. The winkeloptie is an item in a listbox.

Comment: Post more code. Problem can't be reproduced as [it's working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/f4DWU/) using exact code you posted. So it's something with the way you get `winkeloptie` before the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
var y=document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
alert("Index: " + y[x].index + " is " + y[x].text);
```